# Sorbet contain ice crystals

Tags: ice-cream, sorbet

I bought the ICE-30BC ice cream machine from cuisinart after reading hundreds of reviews on amazon and youtube
They all said that it will make a smooth and creamy ice cream.

I tried the red fruits sorbet:
Raspberry
Strawberry
With sugar syrup

When I churned the mix and taste the mix it was smooth and delicious but when I kept it in the fridge for the next day it was hard and I felt the ice crystals when I ate a portion.

The reason is the machine ? The fridge or a missing ingredient ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tips for Creating a Creamy and Smooth Sorbet](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/21891/tips-for-creating-a-creamy-and-smooth-sorbet)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few possibilities, hard to say given the amount of detail:

- you didn't blend the mixture smooth enough, so you have ice crystals from the water in small pieces of fruit that were left
- you didn't churn it long enough, so when it finished freezing in the freezer, it developed larger ice crystals, while if it'd been churned longer they'd have been smaller
- your recipe has too little sugar (too much fruit/water, including what was in the syrup), so it was never going to work out

See also [What determines whether a sherbet will set or not?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/23278/1672) and [Is there a magic ingredient that keeps ice-cream soft?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/12777/1672), among many other past questions on soft sorbet/sherbet/ice cream.

Comment: Can you recommend a good ice cream recipe book ?

Comment: @droidnation My personal favorite is The Perfect Scoop, but I imagine there's a lot of other good stuff out there. I'd try [chat] if you want to talk about book (or recipe) recommendations, though.

Comment: The best references I have come across (if you prefer video to text, you can also watch them...I prefer text.) http://www.goodeatsfanpage.com/season1/churn/churntranscript.htm and http://www.goodeatsfanpage.com/season9/ice_cream/churn_baby_churn_ii.htm